# Error-in-Dependent-Variable in Panel Data

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, standard-error, finance, errors-in-variables

Given an unbalanced panel of data points $(X_{i,t})$, I calculate variances in a rolling window (labelled $Y_{i,t}$). I want to calculate the **time series mean of cross-sectional averages** of this generated variable $Y_{i,t}$. In Fama-MacBeth (1973) language, I estimate an OLS regression of $Y_{i,t}$ on a constant for each time period $t$ and then calculate the mean of the time series of intercepts. I calculate the standard error using Newey-West (1987) correction.

**Question:** How do I incorporate the fact that $Y_{i,t}$ is a generated regressand (similar to Shanken correction for independent variables)?